# Syntax and "in" keyword in Ocaml

Tags: syntax, ocaml, keyword

Original Code 1:

```
# let f x = x ^ "world" in f "hello "
```

Original code 2:

```
# let f x = x ^ "world" in f, "hello"
```

My question is, do these have the correct syntax? If not, what is wrong with it/them, and what is the difference between the two?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest typing them in to the toplevel to get some insight. If they aren't syntactically correct the toplevel will tell you. It will also tell you the values, which should let you figure out the difference.

If you don't have a toplevel handy, I found one that works at http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.5/files/toplevel/index.html. (Type an expression, then Return.)

**Update**

Since you're having trouble running the code, here's what I see when I run it:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let f x = x ^ "world" in f "hello ";;
- : string = "hello world"
# let f x = x ^ "world" in f, "hello";;
- : (string -> string) * string = (<fun>, "hello")
#
```

Comment: I did, and both gave syntax errors. I still do not know what is wrong with the syntax here and would like to know

Comment: They are both syntactically correct. Maybe you typed the '#' at the beginning? That represents the prompt from the toplevel. You should type the rest. Type `;;` at the end of each to get the toplevel to evaluate.

Comment: I created a file in emacs and then ran it. I did not have the hashtag in the code thats in the file. I called it in ocaml by using #use "filename";; to run it and it outputted "Error: Syntax error" for both.

Comment: The code you give above is syntactically valid. I'll update my answer to show this with an OCaml toplevel. With emacs and external file in the picture, many things could have gone wrong.